# High chart date time conversion showing wrong values

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Below is my simple graph on high charts. Everything appears fine but only problem I have now my data is just two 2012-05-26 01:00:00, 200 and 2012-05-26 02:00:00,300. The y-axis appears fine. But on the x-axis it appear the time as start at 17:00 and ends at 18:00 and it does not even show the date even. What could be the problem?

```
<?php
    define('DB_HOST', '*******');
    define('DB_USER', 'user1');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test1');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'db1');

 $dbcnx = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
 mysql_select_db('db1');

$sql = "select unix_timestamp(datetime1) as datetime1, value1 from data";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$dbcnx);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   //extract $row;
   //$datetime1 = $row['dateTime1']*1000;
   $datetime = $row['datetime1']*1000; 
   //echo $datetime;
   echo $row['value1'];
   $val  = $row['value1'];
   // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
   $data[] = "[$datetime, $val]";
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //alert("TS");
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25

      },

      series: 
        [{
         data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
      }],
      xAxis: { type: 'datetime'}

   });
  });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what data you are passing the highchart.  By the sounds of it you are only passing it two data points.  Did you verify that the query is pulling the data you want?  If so, can you post here the data that should be in the highchart?  Also, can you post here the highcharts that is generated in the view source of the webpage?

As far as the xaxis labels, since they are of datetime format, then the chart will render them the best way it sees fit.  If you don't like the way they are rendered, you can control the datetime formats of the chart using [dateTimeLabelFormats](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--dateTimeLabelFormats).  You can also control the interval of the dates shown using [tickInterval](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--tickInterval).

Comment: the data is confirmed from mysql query in this format "2012-05-12 09:00:00". I have managed to format but is like interval between one day to another day is it possible to make the interval every 12 hours?

Comment: Yes the interval can be set to every 12 hours.  For a datetime HighCharts uses milliseconds.  There are 3600000 milliseconds in an hour.  If the axis is set at `type: 'datetime'` and the interval is set at `tickInterval: 43200000` then it will be intervals of 12 hours.

Comment: Why is it 43200000? Any reason for it why not 1800000?

Comment: Well since there is 1000 milliseconds in a second, if you do the math, that is just what it comes to. `1000 * 60 * 60 * 12 = 43200000`